# WordPress Multisite has one site that gets a 500 error on the homepage on the first load

Tags: php, wordpress, server, multisite

Title pretty much sums up the issue. A client has a multisite and one of the sites returns a 500 error when opening in a fresh browser until you perform a hard refresh.

Screen is completely white (on firefox) and doesn't output any errors when setting WP_DEBUG to true.

We were getting LimitInternalRecursion errors and we've tried everything we could find around that.

The .htaccess config is the default multisite config besides stuff added by plugins like wp rocket and really simple ssl.

It's really strange because it's literally the one site and just the homepage.

site: https://survive-a-storm.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caching problem more than accessing problem. If you are using cache plugins or maybe something in your hosting panel, check it.

I know Wp-rocket setting has many option for loading pages from hosting.

Last thing is using CDN, if you have it, check it.